# How does Octopus deploy interact with hashicorp vault to get secrets and certificates?

Tags: hashicorp-vault, octopus-deploy

1. how to create secrets and certs in hashivault?
2. How to pull those secrets into my octopus deploy?

Answer (score 0):

[Looking at the documentation](https://library.octopus.com/listing), you can't write secrets in Vault from your pipeline. A part of your pipeline, maybe a Terraform or Ansible, will generate secrets and store them in Vault, for another part of the pipeline to retrieve them later.

Once you have secrets to retrieve, you will need to

1. [Authenticate to Vault](https://library.octopus.com/step-templates/e04a9cec-f04a-4da2-849b-1aed0fd408f0/actiontemplate-hashicorp-vault-approle-login)
2. [Pull the secrets](https://library.octopus.com/step-templates/337f1b67-cdb0-4f33-9e08-6bf804f672d2/actiontemplate-hashicorp-vault-key-value-(v2)-retrieve-secrets)

I suggest that you start write and reading secrets and certificate from the command line first, to quickly get a sense of how Vault works. Something like:

```
vault kv put secret/octopus/dev/pipeline-1 my-secret=hello123
vault kv get secret/octopus/dev/pipeline-1
```